# Is *, html selector redundant?

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

I often see web developers use the following:

```
*, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

But I would have thought that would be redundant, since `*` matches all elements. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I have never seen web developers use that, ever.

Comment: I have used a * in the past, but it select's all elements. So why would you need to select html as well?

Comment: Are you thinking of the [star html hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack), perhaps?

Comment: I was not, but it's very interesting....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't redundant if you are in need of more specificity to protect from an override default style on an `html` selector maybe such as in the case of changing font styles.

However, `*` will match an `html` tag.

You can read more about [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) here.

**Edit:**

Example case usage:

if you have a default set of styles you include on every page to override browser defaults that includes this:

```
*,html {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

then later a different css file happens to have the same selector for a different case:

```
* {
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Then your `html` will remain unaffected because a `*` has no specificity for starters which means the rule is overturned by the previous css rule.

I added a font changing example that does this on the `body` tag to demonstrate the concept - http://jsfiddle.net/M89Tn/1/

Comment: @thirtydot /agree =P Just showing how it is technically not redundant to do.